# c++ remove multiples of a given integer from a linked list

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

sorry for my ignorance but i'm both new here and on C++. I'm studying linked list and there is an exercise where i have to write a function that takes in input a list of integers and integer n. The function has to remove from the list all the nodes with a multiple of n and return the list. I thought i did it right but my code doesn't output anything. Could someone explain me why? Thank you all!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct list{
    int val;
    list* next;
};
typedef list* ptr_list;

ptr_list new_node(ptr_list old_node, int value);

ptr_list remove_mult(ptr_list head, int n);

void print_list(ptr_list head);

int main() {

    ptr_list head, p1, p2, p3;
    head = new list;
    head->val = 1;
    p1 = new_node(head, 2);
    p2 = new_node(p1, 3);
    p3 = new_node(p2, 4);

    p3->next = NULL;

    remove_mult(head, 2);
    print_list(head);

    return(0);
}

ptr_list new_node(ptr_list old_node, int value)
{
    old_node->next = new list;
    old_node->next->val = value;
    return old_node->next;
}


ptr_list remove_mult(ptr_list head, int n){
    ptr_list prev, curr;
    prev = head;
    curr = head->next;
    while(curr->next != NULL){
        if((head->val % n) == 0){
            head = head->next;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        else if((curr->val % n) == 0){
            ptr_list tmp;
            tmp = prev->next;
            prev->next = tmp->next;
            delete tmp;
        }
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    if((curr->val % n) == 0){
        prev->next = NULL;
        delete curr;
    }
    return(head);
}

void print_list(ptr_list head){
    while ( head != NULL ){
        cout << head->val << " ";
        head = head->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: `head = new list` creates a new node for the head itself, But what about `head->next`? Where does it point? Where do you create an object for that?

Comment: Does this actually run? `head->next` is not allocated neither the following `next`s...

Comment: Off-topic: It's bad style to typedef pointers (sure, Microsoft people do so all the time, but that doesn't make it any better...), in the end, you are just hiding information without *any* benefit (unless hiding that information is your explicit goal, e. g. for some kind of handles to system resources, rather typical for C-only interfaces).

Comment: `if(condition) { } else if(!condition) { }` is pretty meaningless – unless condition might have changed in the meanwhile (in multi-threading scenarios!). You can just have `if(condition) { } else { }` instead.

Comment: Don't place parentheses around return values! `return` is not a function, and in worst case, these parentheses even can change the semantics of your function, e. g. `decltype(auto) f() { int n; return (n); }` will produce a (dangling!) reference to local variable n.

Comment: You don't consider the case where head contains a multiple of n! And you might consider returning the new head – instead of a pointer to somewhere inside the list (imagine you have a list with no multiples at all, where would `head` point to at the very end?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach

```
ptr_list head, p1, p2, p3;
head = new list;
head->val = 1;
p1 = new_node(head, 2);
p2 = new_node(p1, 3);
p3 = new_node(p2, 4);

p3->next = NULL;

//...

ptr_list new_node(ptr_list old_node, int value)
{
    old_node->next = new list;
    old_node->next->val = value;
    return old_node->next;
}
```

is bad because it is unsafe. For example the user can pass to the function a null-pointer. Or the data member next of the passed pointer can point to a valid node. In this case it will be overwritten in the function and there will be a memory leak. Or the user can forget to set the data member next of the last node after exiting the function to `nullptr`.

The function `remove_mult` is also invalid. For example the passed pointer in general can be equal to `nullptr`. In this case the function has undefined behavior.

```
ptr_list remove_mult(ptr_list head, int n){
    ptr_list prev, curr;
    prev = head;
    curr = head->next;
    //...
```

The function has also a memory leak because you forgot to delete the head node in this if statement

```
    if((head->val % n) == 0){
        head = head->next;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
```

In this else statement

```
    else if((curr->val % n) == 0){
        ptr_list tmp;
        tmp = prev->next;
        prev->next = tmp->next;
        delete tmp;
    }
```

you forgot to set the new value of the variable `curr`.

After the if-else statement

```
    prev = curr;
    curr = curr->next;
```

you are setting `prev` one more time. This again results in undefined behavior for example when the current node was deleted.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the functions for the list can be implemented.

```
#include <iostream>

struct list
{
    int val;
    list* next;
};

typedef list* ptr_list;

ptr_list remove_mult(ptr_list head, int n )
{
    ptr_list curr = head;
    ptr_list prev = nullptr;

    while ( curr != nullptr )
    {
        if ( curr->val % n == 0 )
        {
            ptr_list tmp = curr;

            if ( prev == nullptr )
            {
                head = curr = curr->next;
            }
            else
            {
                curr = prev->next = curr->next;
            }

            delete tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }

    return head;
}

void print_list( ptr_list head )
{
    for ( ; head != nullptr; head = head->next )
    {
        std::cout << head->val << ' ';
    }
}

ptr_list append_list( ptr_list tail, int val )
{
    if ( tail == nullptr )
    {
        tail = new list { val, nullptr };
    }
    else
    {
        while ( tail->next != nullptr )
        {
            tail = tail->next;
        }

        tail->next = new list { val, nullptr };
        tail = tail->next;
    }

    return tail;
}

int main() 
{
    ptr_list head = nullptr;

    const int N = 10;

    ptr_list tail = nullptr;
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        if ( head == nullptr )
        {
            head = append_list( head, i );
            tail = head;
        }
        else
        {
            tail = append_list( tail, i );
        }
    }

    print_list( head );
    std::cout << '\n';

    head = remove_mult( head, 2 );

    print_list( head );
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
1 3 5 7 9
```